# How can I configure avahi to resolve host name on adhoc network?

Tags: debian, avahi

I have a linux machine (raspberry pi) running Debian and I have configured it to create an ad-hoc network. The machine hosts a web app which allows a person to scan for infrastructure networks and select one and enter security credentials. The raspberry pi will then connect up to the chosen network.

I want to make it simple to get to the webpage hosted by the raspberry pi, regardless of whether it in ad-hoc mode or infrastructure mode. From what I have read, the best way to do this is to install `avahi-daemon` and configure it to resolve the hostname to it's own address. I have tried doing this but ran into some problems. When the pi is connected to an infrastructure I can run `ping raspberrypi.local` on my mac and get ping responses back from the pi. However, when the pi is in ad-hoc mode, and I connect my mac up to the adhoc network, the ping does not succeed. It seems as though avahi is only working with infrastructure networking mode.

Here is my attempt:

I added the following service definition in `/etc/avahi/services`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE  service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
    <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
    <service>
        <type>_device-info._tcp</type>
        <port>0</port>
        <txt-record>model=RackMac</txt-record>
    </service>
    <service>
        <type>_ssh._tcp</type>
        <port>22</port>
    </service>
    <service>
        <type>_http._tcp</type>
        <port>80</port>
    </service>
</service-group>
```

The avahi config file `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` is the same as the default one but I tried adding the following:

```
allow-point-to-point=yes
```

which did not help. I thought maybe point-to-point was the same as peer-to-peer network, but maybe not?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:
I'm not sure if it's important or not but I do also have dhcpd running when the Pi is in ad-hoc mode. Could this be a problem? Does avahi try to assign IP addresses?

Comment: Read [this First](http://www.howtogeek.com/180649/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-ad-hoc-and-infrastructure-mode/).  It was always my understanding that if no device on the ad hoc network was functioning as a router, you couldn't see the Internet, only information shard between devices

Comment: I'm not trying to access the internet though

Comment: I think this is a neat idea!

Comment: did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I think Avahi needs `nss-mdns` which is a glibc plugin providing host name resolution via mDNS, and avahi daemon started on bootup.

> Suppose you have machines with names maple, fig and oak, all running Avahi. Avahi can be set up so that you do not have to manage a /etc/hosts file for each computer. Instead you can simply use maple.local to access whatever services maple has.

You can get more info on ArchLinux [wikipage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/avahi#Hostname_resolution) (refer to **Arch's** or **Gentoo** wikipages frequently. These two have simply the ***best*** documentation available :) )

Comment: I think you might be right. I was thinking that nss-mdns was a dependancy of avahi and thus installed automatically, however I just checked and it is listed as a recommended package, not a a dependancy. I will give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: bummer it turns out I did already have libnss-mdns installed. doesn't seem to do the trick.